# What is the main verb in this sentence? And is "Several previous deals to end the fighting in Idlib" a noun phrase?

Tags: grammar

i still confused about identifying the main verb and distinguish phrase and clause including this sentence: *Several previous deals to end the fighting in Idlib have collapsed*

What is the main verb in this sentence? Is "Several previous deals to end the fighting in Idlib" a noun phrase?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Yes: "several previous deals to end the fighting in Idlib" is a noun phrase. If by 'main' verb you mean the matrix (main clause) verb , then it's "have". "Collapsed" is a subordinate clause functioning as complement of "have", and is thus the subordinate verb.

Comment: [correction: I am still confused etc.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb is "collapsed" and yes, "Several previous deals to end the fighting in Idlib" is a noun phrase.

it may be easier to visualize if we simplify the sentence by taking out some details. In the sentence "The deals collapsed," the noun phrase is "The deals" and the verb is "collapsed."

Comment: "Collapsed" is a subordinate clause functioning as complement of "have", so syntactically the matrix verb is "have" and "collapsed" is the subordinate verb.

Comment: It might be more helpful for the OP to just look at it as the present perfect form of *collapse* though. I think the confusion might have been around having "to end" in there as well

Answer (score 0):

The main verb is "to collapse" in the present perfect simple tense: "have collapsed".

The subject of the sentence is indeed "Several previous deals to end the fighting in Idlib" (and yes, you're right; it is a noun clause).

Answer (score 0):

**A learner's guide**

Parsing a sentence according to the question:

/Several previous deals //to end the fighting in Idlib// have collapsed.

> the infinitive may function as a subject, direct object, subject
> complement, adjective, or adverb in a sentence. Although an infinitive
> is easy to locate because of the to + verb form, *deciding what
> function it has in a sentence can sometimes be confusing*.
> [Purdue Writing Lab](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/gerunds_participles_and_infinitives/infinitives.html)

to end the fighting in Idlib=can be viewed as a subject complement, used in an infinitive phrase. A subject complement says something about the subject of the sentence.

several previous deals=subject of the sentence
have collapsed=verb

If you remove the infinitive phrase, you still get a clause with meaning and this makes the verb stand out:
/Several previous deals have collapsed/.

The main verb is have collapsed.